# Remove duplicates from result in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

i have following sql in java project:

```
select distinct * from drivers inner join licenses on  drivers.user_id=licenses.issuer_id
        inner join users on drivers.user_id=users.id 
        where (licenses.state='ISSUED' or drivers.status='WAITING')
        and users.is_deleted=false
```

And result i database looks like this:
[image]

And **i would like to get only one result instead of two duplicated results.**
How can i do that?

Comment: Which one do you want?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: You need to provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 - That's Because one of data has duplicate value write distinct keyword with only column you want like this

```
Select distinct id, distinct  creation_date, distinct  modification_date from 
YourTable
```

Solution 2 - apply distinct only on ID and once you get id you can get all data using in query

```
select * from yourtable where id in (select distinct id from drivers inner join 
 licenses 
 on drivers.user_id=licenses.issuer_id
 inner join users on drivers.user_id=users.id 
 where (licenses.state='ISSUED' or drivers.status='WAITING')
 and users.is_deleted=false )
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum fields name on select, using COALESCE for fields which value is null.

Answer (score 0):

usually you dont query distinct with * (all columns), because it means if one column has the same value but the rest isn't, it will be treated as a different rows. so you have to distinct only the column you want to, then get the data

Comment: ok so it is not possible to do that in only one sql right? "so you have to distinct only the column you want to, then get the data"- yes i can distincst only one column and i will receive id i need, but i would like to get all data(not only id)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want `left join`s like this:

```
select *
from users u left join
     drivers d
     on d.user_id = u.id and d.status = 'WAITING' left join
     licenses l
     on d.user_id = l.issuer_id and l.state = 'ISSUED'
where u.is_deleted = false and
      (d.user_id is not null or l.issuer_id is not null);
```